# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2, install

Устанавливаю pgAdmin 4.

```
pip install pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl
```

И выводит в конце такое

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-build-aofWrQ/psycopg2/

Полный текст:

```
Collecting psycopg2==2.6.2 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz (376kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 2.1MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-aofWrQ/psycopg2/
```

То, что написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c) не помогает, по крайней мере первый ответ.

Comment: Попробуй глянуть тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info

Comment: @And это тоже уже делал 'pip install --upgrade setuptools'

Comment: Давайте более полный вывод ошибки, так как конец абсолютно неинформативен

Comment: @andreymal добавил

Comment: Такое, чувство, что несовместимость какая-то, хотя странновато все это. Какая версия питона и под какую качаете версию? Попробуйте снести и поставить актуальные версии.

Comment: @And Python 2.7.12 и Python 3.5.2 . и там и там те же ошибки

Comment: Кстати, а вы добавили в  PATH - полный путь до pg_config ? Можно сделать export PATH = <полный путь>:"$PATH" и потом pip install psycopg2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не установлен psycorg2 (зависимость pgadmin4 вероятно). При установки pgadmin4, pip автоматически пытается установить необходимые зависимости (только Питон библиотеки—pip не ставит стороннее не Питон ПО как правило).

Ошибка в вопросе возникает из-за попытки компиляции psycorg2 из исходников (не найдена команда `pg_config`). На моей системе, `/usr/bin/pg_config` находится в `postgresql-common` Ubuntu пакете (это не важно, так как фактическую системную установку `sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2` или схожая команда выполняет).

Установите psycorg2 нужной версии на вашу систему и повторите pip команду для pgadmin4.

Нас интересует версия, которая видна pip команде:

```
$ pip show psycopg2
```

Если хочется более новую версию из исходников собрать, то чтобы автоматически зависимости для компиляции поставить, можно выполнить:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2
```

И заново запустить  `pip install` с желаемыми ограничениями на версию.

Comment: оно установило python-psycopg2, но при установке pgadmin4 все равно тоже самое выдает

Comment: Какая версия установлена `psycopg2==2.6.2`?

Comment: dpkg -s psycopg2 - "dpkg-query: package 'psycopg2' is not installed and no information is available"

Comment: dpkg -s python-psycopg2 - "Package: python-psycopg2
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 677
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: psycopg2
Version: 2.6.1-1build2
"

Comment: @SkiesX нас интересует версия, которая видна pip  команде: `pip show <package>`. Вывод `dpkg -s` говорит, что 2.6.1 а не 2.6.2 установлена. Как более новую версию psycopg2 поставить, спросите ввиде отдельного вопроса (Можете попробовать pgadmin4 также как Ubuntu пакет поставить (более старую версию) или ppa с новой версией psycorg2 или поставить (apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2) необходимые lib\* пакеты для компиляции psycopg2 из исходников).

Comment: установил это пакет 'libpq-dev' и все заработало)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618898/pg-config-executable-not-found

Comment: @SkiesX упомянутая build-dep команда эту зависимость автоматически должна поставить.

Comment: А можете в сам ответ переписать текст того коммента, ну чтобы я уже поставил галочку, что вопрос решен и то верный ответ. Да и чтобы народ потом не лазил в комменты, а сразу в ответе прочитал.

Comment: @SkiesX: ответ на ваш вопрос: "поставьте psycorg2 нужной версии". Как поставить psycorg2, если очевидные шаги не работают. это уже отдельный вопрос (решение в комментарии работает для Ubuntu, но этот ответ не подходящее место, чтобы инструкции по устанвоке psycorg2 приводить).

Comment: возникла опять эта же ошибка только с установкой вот этого https://github.com/MrS0m30n3/google-translate

Comment: @SkiesX *"Эта же ошибка"*? Вы же поставили psycopg2? Если вы имеете ввиду, что `"python setup.py"` с ошибкой завершился, то это просто значит, что один из шагов инсталляции/сборки пакета неудачно завершился. Причины могут быть самыми разными в зависимости от модуля, которые вы пытаетесь установить 1- приведите команду, которую выполняли 2- приведите полный вывод команды, traceback и спросите отдельный вопрос, упомянув ошибку и какой пакет ставите (если при установке эта ошибка возникает).

Comment: `psycopg2` поставил. теперь ставляю пакет для работы с Google Translate. Вот этот https://github.com/MrS0m30n3/google-translate и выдает `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zcnvnkng/doodle-translate/`

Answer (score 13):

Установите следующий пакет:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: Этот ответ должен быт принят как лучший. Первый ответ сбивает с толку и `psycopg2` вовсе ни при чем. Точнее он не может установиться с зависимостями `pgAdmin` из-за отсутсвия `pq-dev` в системе, но это не повод ставить его отдельно через `pip` или еще хуже системным пакетом `python-psycopg2`.

Кстати, в `Alpine` Linux необходимый пакет называется `postgresql-dev`.